# Developing android app. Trying to resolve external usb device respring

Tags: android

So I have an app that connects to an external usb device on my Nexus phone. When I connect the usb device to the phone, the app automatically opens and I can hit the start button on the phone app to start collecting data from an acceletometer on the external usb device. I can hit stop, and the data collected gets stored in a specific folder on my phone. When I hit start again, the phone collects data for a second, but then immediately stops collecting data. When I power off the external usb device and turn it back on, and i can collect data normally. The app only seems to collect data once. I'd like to make it so I dont have to reset the external usb device every time I want to collect data. Any advice is highly appriciated and thank you all in advance!

Comment: All one can really say is to load up the code with tons of logging and figure out what is going on.  Develop suspects and set traps for them with more logging.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Its been driving me nuts trying to figure out what's going on.